# What is the difference between amplitude and phase angle for a pendulum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, terminology, definition, oscillators

I understand the definition in terms a plain trigonometric function, such as $A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$. The **amplitude** is half of the distance between peak and bottom, and the *phase angle** is how the function shifts horizontally.

However, I am having a hard time grasp how would these two terms apply to a real-world pendulum.  If a pendulum's **amplitude** is the maximum displacement from its equilibrium position, then what is its **phase angle**?
Is it the initial displacement? If so, wouldn't the phase angle already determine the amplitude, if we simply release the pendulum without applying any extra force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a solution of the (linearized) equation of motion for the pendulum,
$$\theta(t)=A\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}t+\varphi\right).$$
The amplitude $|A|$ is the maximum value of $\theta$; the angle varies between $-|A|$ and $|A|$ in the course of each period of length $T=2\pi\sqrt{l/g}$.

The phase angle $\varphi$ tells you where in the cycle the pendulum is at any particular time.  For example, if you start with the pendulum lifted up to an angle $\theta_{0}$ and you release it at time $t=0$, the solution will have $A=\theta_{0}$ and $\varphi=0$, since the initial conditions have $\theta(0)$ at a maximum and the angular velocity $\dot{\theta}(0)=0$.  If instead you start the pendulum at its equilibrium position at $t=0$, but with a nonzero angular velocity $\dot{\theta}(0)>0$, the phase angle will be $\varphi=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ (or $-90^{\circ}$), making the solution
$$\theta(t)=A\cos\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}t-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=
A\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}t\right).$$